# Can I say that $R= Rr + I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be a maximal left ideal of a ring $R$. I have $y \in radR$ e $r \in R$. I am assuming that $yr \notin I$. Can I say that $R= Rr + I$?

*Definition:* $rad R$ is a intesection of the maximal left ideals of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: this argument does not hold up since your assumptions are inconsistent.

If $y\in rad(R)$, then $yr\in rad(R)\subseteq I$, since $rad(R)$ is an ideal. It is impossible for $yr\notin I$.

If you drop the condition that $y\in rad(R)$, and you assume $yr\notin I$, then $Ryr+I=R$ for exactly the reason Matt Samuel gave, namely: for any left ideal $N$ such that $N\nsubseteq I$ we have $N+I=R$, since $N+I$ is a left ideal of $R$ properly containing $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For any element $x\notin I$ we have that $Rx+I=R$ because $I$ is a maximal ideal. Thus $Ryr+I=R$. Also, $Ryr\subseteq Rr$, so it is true even more so (if such a thing is possible) that $Rr+I=R$.